# What are other possible functions i can access

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-view, magento-catalog, product-details

I created placed custom html in `Magento_Catalog>template>product>view>details.phtml` file in `Magento_Catalog` module and added below code to get current product ID and name

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$_product_id = $product->getId();
$_product_name = $product->getName();
```

What are the other functions to get product details like Price, Images, Short & Long description, etc...

Please sugest me the list of functions i can use to get product details.

Please help me if you know answer to [this Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280152/modify-product-page-ui-with-custom-html-body-and-load-the-data) also

Comment: You can take reference from this file for get product details `magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get price,sku,description by following code

```
$_product_price = $product->getPrice();
$_product_image= $product->getImage();
$_product_sku = $product->getSku();
$_product_desc=$product->getDescription();
```

updated solution
get category ids and images by following code

```
protected $_productRepositoryFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory
) {

    $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
}
```

In function

```
 $_items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($_items as $_item)
{
    $id=$_item->getProductId();
}

$product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($item->getProductId());
$product->getData('image');
$product->getData('thumbnail');
$product->getData('small_image');
$product->getCategoryIds();
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: I'll try that. how can we get images of the same product? getGallery??? and category also? getCategory?

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check my another question. no one replied to me on that one! :(

Comment: Did you check updated answer?

Comment: Yes its working fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You current_product is the object of following class:

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

Path:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php

Now you open this class and search your actual method.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will list you a functions list to get product data according to your code.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(get_class_methods($product));
```

Hope it helps.